# DELL INSPIRON 1100 15" LAPTOP with no os

Tags: dell

How do i  install ubuntu on a DELL INSPIRON 1100 15" LAPTOP with no Preloaded OS?

Comment: Too vague. You are having problems with what? Why is this: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop not good enough to get you started? Does that machine have a dvd? or USB ports? Do you have a Ubuntu installer on a disc/stick? And not you are not going to get someone to type a whole bunch of faq, tips and tricks based on 1 single line.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a PC with a Internet Connection just download Ubuntu 14.04 LTS from here -
http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop

1. If you have a DVD reader/writer Slot then create a live CD/DVD(not recommended too slow)
2. If you have a USB slot(As all machines have) then burn a USB Flash Drive with UBUNTU iso file and that's all you need for installation.
3. Just insert live USB into your computer and in boot menu go for boot from secondary device option ( even if you don't do that the USB will be detected as a boot option)
4. follow Installation Procedure - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick 
   Rembember you need an active pc with internet connection and a USB Flash or CD as bootable (live) media
   Also if you need more on creating bootable USB Flash Drive read following

-http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

You can also connect your laptop to internet connection and perform a Network installation (read following to do so)..

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/Netboot

This is easier one directly installing from Internet
-https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/NetbootInstallFromInternet?

Comment: Lost bet dude sorry about that... :D